# Reporting register usage in clang cuda

Tags: cuda, clang

I cannot find it in docs: does `clang` provide an option similar to nvcc's `-Xptxas=-v` to report register usage (and spills, frame-buffer, etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [here](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html)

```
-Xcuda-ptxas <arg>

Pass <arg> to the ptxas assembler
```